# Why second frame has wrong PTS value when decoding with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, pts

I'm using `ffmpeg` to encode video to mp4.
I have MP4 that were encoded with different GOP & bitrate values.

When I decode the video frame by frame the `pkt_pts` of each successive frame should increase in time base units. 

Some of the MP4s jump in correct successive pts values. For `time_base={num=1, den=12800}` and `frame_rate={num=1, den=25}` the `interval=512 (12800/25)`: first frame has `pts=0`, second frame has `pts=512`, third frame has `pts=1024`,...

But, there are MP4s that though the frames jump in correct pts values, the **SECOND** frame has wrong pts value. For `time_base={num=1, den=1200000}` and `frame_rate={num=1, den=16}` the `interval=75000 (1200000/16)`: the first frame has `pts=0`, the second frame has `pts=48000`, the third frame has `pts=123000`. 
Why the second frame has `pts=48000` and not `pts=75000`?

I'm trying to understand what parameters can cause this.

If you need more information in order to address this question please let me know.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: the third frame and all after are OK? Command line and console output of an encoding please?

Comment: the third frame is 123000 (48000+75000), the 4th is 198000. So, starting from second frame and further the interval is as expected 75000. But, the interval between the first and second is 48000.

Comment: not clear why it would be that way, guess you could ask on the ffmpeg-user mailing list (or ffmpeg trac, give a reproducible example) GL!